# Can't control brightness from xfce

Tags: linux, laptop, backlight

Okay so at first I thought I needed to configure kernel because I wasn't able to adjust brightness, however, I can adjust brightness directly using file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness. What's the solution for this problem, so far I didn't find anything useful.

Laptop: Samsung R428
Distro: openSUSE Tumbleweed

Answer (score 1):

I should've read [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Kernel_command-line_options) more carefully. Adding `acpi_backlight=none` in kernel parameters fixed this problem entierly.

Comment: Welcome to SU! Even if it's a self-answered question, please mark the answer as correct (after enough time has passed for others to also have an opportunity to answer). This way, we can keep the number of open questions down.